# What should I do to get into competitive?

Tags: team-fortress-2, competitive-gaming

I've been playing a lot of pubs for a long time.  What steps should I take if I want to give competitive TF2 a shot?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can freely join leagues (like the [UGC](http://www.ugcleague.com/home_tf28.cfm)) to get yourself noticed.  You may also be able to network with other players and build your own team.

Another option is to pug for competitive teams.  Idle on IRC (like gamesurge) and offer your services.

Comment: How many players do you need to form a competitive team?

Comment: @jacen.garriss For Highlander, it was 9, one for each class

Comment: What does it mean to 'pug' for a team?

Comment: @Zibboz: pugging refers to playing in a competitive match on behalf of a team that would otherwise be down a player.

Answer (score 4):

One source I found was [TF2Center](http://tf2center.com/).  This will automatically set you up into a pick-up-group, so you don't have to manually organize one over IRC.